# Does 'echo user:pass | /usr/sbin/chpasswd' override the root password?

Tags: unix, change-password

On a work server I server I created a new user called Dev-admin. This user has Root permissions. The password was incorrect and needed to be changed.

I ran the `chpasswd` command as seen below to change it

```
 echo user:pass | /usr/sbin/chpasswd
```

This was successful, however, when I changed users with `su - Dev-admin` the user displayed was:

`root@domain` instead of `Dev-admin@domain`

Is this only because Dev-admin has root privileges? I am afraid that I changed the original root password instead of just the Dev-admin one.

Comment: do you try to check is there any new user create by using this command?
cat /etc/passwd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that Linux does not recognize your username as a username in the command but as part of the command and fails to execute your username as part of the command and instead executes `su -` instead and returned with `root@domain` because your username has one of these symbols `.`, `-` and `_` and is referred to as a `BadName` in Linux. Try changing your username to a different name, like for example, instead of **Dev-admin**, try using **devadmin** instead. So don't be afraid, you didn't change the password of the root user.